# Create a production-order matrix from given sequences

Tags: python, dataframe, sequence

I am new to python and could need your help.

I want to generate a DataFrame which shows the order of production.
Therefore I created different sequences, depending on the number of products. For example for 2 and 3 products:

```
seq_2 = [[0, 0], [1, 0]] 
seq_3 = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
```

Now, depending on the number of products (which can be seen from the number of columns in another matrix), I select the appropriate number with:

```
sequence = 'seq_'+str(len(df.columns))
```

The result, creating a DataFrame for 2 products, should look like:

```
matrix = pd.DataFrame(sequence, columns=products, index=products) 

       Prod1  Prod2 
Prod1    0      1  
Prod2    0      0
```

Unfortunately, it looks like this:

```
       Prod1  Prod2 
Prod1  seq_2  seq_2  
Prod2  seq_2  seq_2
```

I think there is something wrong with my sequence definition.

Comment: pd.Dataframe is set to be created by `sequence`, and `sequence` is a string here. Do you want to make the dataframe out of your `seq_2/3` nested lists?

Comment: yes exactly, but depending on the number of products (1 to 6) its seq_2 to seq_6

Comment: so why are you inputting a string as the data for the dataframe?